# Castle Windsor ResolveAll using key in multiple componentss

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Is there a way to resolve all types for a giving service using a key and that key is used several times? This is not meant for dependency injection. 
What I want to achieve is group components, and get list of those components in a group.
For example, I have an interface:

```
interface ICommand  
{  
   void Execute();  
}
```

I want to use this interface for several purposes, each purpose will may have multiple implementations and I do not want to create an interface for each purpose, I want to use this ICommand interface.
I want to be able to do something like below:

```
ICommand[] commands = container.ResolveAll<ICommand>("purpose1");  
ICommand[] commands2 = container.ResolveAll<ICommand>("purpose2");
```

Above assumes registration has already been performed.
Does anyone have any idea about how to do this?
I know Castle Windsor is meant to do Dependency Injection but I found it helpful for this purpose, I know this can be done using MEF naturally but some components do have dependencies that MEF as fas I know will not inject.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you register `ICommand[]` instead of `ICommand`?

Comment: To be able to do it as you suggest I need to know in a single place all components for a single purpose which may not be the case @yacoub

Comment: BTW thanks @YacoubMassad

Answer (score 1):

As I undestand giving a key name is to distinct it from multiple implementations of same service under the container.

Probably you can define a property at the service that can hold the name of the group the implementation belong.

Using UnityContainer you could do something as follow:

```
interface ICommand  
{  
   void Execute();
   string GroupName { get; }
} 

class CommandImpl1 : ICommand 
{
  void Execute() { ... }
  string GroupName { get { return "group1"; }
}

class CommandImpl2 : ICommand 
{
  void Execute() { ... }
  string GroupName { get { return "group1"; }
}
```

Then you can register:

```
Container.Register<ICommand, CommandImpl1>("a");
Container.Register<ICommand, CommandImpl2>("b");
```

And pull all for the group you are looking for:

```
IEnumerable<ICommand> allCommands = Container.ResolveAll<ICommand>();
IEnumerable<ICommand> group1Commands = allCommands
    .Where( cmds => cmds.GroupName.Equals("group1"));
```

Have not test it but it think should work. Another approach could be using an annotation at the implemented service.

Cheers!!

Comment: Biggest issue with this approach is that I would have to add a property to interface which is not acceptable @erickpimienta